# In IntelliJ is there a way to click a variable and check its type (typescript)?

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea

It would be extremely useful to be able to hover over a variable and see what type typescript is expecting it to have. Surely there is static analysis being performed and this information is stored internally. Is there a way to access it?

Comment: That is the way IntelliJ behaves when I use it. Are you asking about how to enable the real TypeScript service instead of JetBrains' custom one?

Comment: @AluanHaddad no, I want to be able to select a variable in the IDE and check what it's computed typescript type is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + `mouse hover` shows the type in Intellij 2016.3.

[image: see type and dynamic type as well]

Comment: This is Java, I am asking about typescript. However, it is similar for typescript. Also, on MacOS (which I'm using) it's command, not control.

Comment: Good comment about how to use this feature in MacOS (I'm using Linux). 
And thank you for accepting  my answer.